# Can I change the value of a property to a SASS variable via vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Can a variable (like `$color = red`) become the value of a CSS property through vanillaJavaScript? `div.color = "$color"` doesn't seem to work for me. This'd suggest to me variables are just really helpful in the designing of a website as it allows the author to quickly compare stylings.

(P.s. I'm aware the standard way to change an element's CSS is for said element's class attribute's value to change e.g. the element's class attribute gets added a value|class selector which adds a whole bunch of CSS rules).

Comment: You can do this easily with CSS, with Sass there are a couple JSON-based packages but I think they're only available server-side

Comment: [This](https://github.com/pmowrer/node-sass-json-importer) package is for node-sass

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I just found this article (https://css-tricks.com/getting-javascript-to-talk-to-css-and-sass/). I'm going to read through this and then maybe look at the package you suggested

Comment: Since Sass is compiled to CSS, there is no way to access a SASS variable in your Javascript. This is because your SASS is compiled before the browser render the page and your Javascript is running when the browser render the page. Depending on what you are trying to do exactly, I would suggest creating classes that could be assign to your div via Javascript and use your SASS variable in those classes.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I followed the article I found but it didn't work. The package that you suggest I don't understand the instructions. Would you be able to pass on an article or Youtube video that shows setting it up?

Comment: I've never used it, I just stick to CSS variables as much as possible. Sorry, @tonitone120

Comment: You can use "vanilla CSS" variables like `var(color)`